# Libgdx game Runs perfect in Eclipse, doesn't even open when Exported

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, tiled

I am creating a Game in java, using LibGdx. It worked perfectly fine when compiled until I added Layers to my Tiled Map. It still runs fine when ran from Eclipse but when i compile it into a runnable jar, it does not even open. I commented out everything to do with Layers and it ran perfect again, so i have no idea what is causing this issue.

Here is the Stack:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mygdx.game.Game_Screen.render(Game_Screen.java:181) at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:‌​215) at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120‌​)
```

And here is the code:

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer.Cell;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;

public class Game_Screen implements Screen{
private TiledMap map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer  renderer;
OrthographicCamera camera;
private static final int        FRAME_COLS = 4;         // #1
private static final int        FRAME_ROWS = 4;         // #2


Animation                       walkAnimationUp;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationUpIdle;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationDown;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationDownIdle;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationLeft;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationLeftIdle;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationRight;          // #3
Animation                       walkAnimationRightIdle;          // #3


Cell cellRight;
int blockedRight = 0;
Cell cellLeft;
int blockedLeft = 0;
Cell cellUp;
int blockedUp = 1;
Cell cellDown;
int blockedDown = 1;

int cellX;
int cellY;
int[] layers = {1,2,3};


Texture                         walkSheet;              // #4
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesUp;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesUpIdle;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesDown;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesDownIdle;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesLeft;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesLeftIdle;             // #5
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesRight;
TextureRegion[]                 walkFramesRightIdle;

int                             boundaryXLeft = 0;
int                             boundaryYDown = 0;
int                             boundaryXRight = 6720;
int                             boundaryYUp = 4032;
MyGdxGame                       game;
SpriteBatch                     spriteBatch;            // #6
TextureRegion                   currentFrame;           // #7
int                             spriteX = 0;
int                             spriteY = 0;
int                             newX = 0;
int                             newY = 0;
int                             LastKey = 0;
int                             CurrentKey = 0;
int                             speed;

float                       stateTime;                                        // #8

boolean                         pause = false;
TiledMapTileLayer               layer;
String collisionLayer;

public Game_Screen(MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = loader.load("ActualMap.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1920, 1080);
    camera.position.set(spriteX,spriteY, stateTime);
    walkSheet = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("newSprite.png")); // #9
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(walkSheet, walkSheet.getWidth()/FRAME_COLS, walkSheet.getHeight()/FRAME_ROWS);              // #10
    walkFramesRight = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesRightIdle = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesLeft = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesLeftIdle = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesUp = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesUpIdle = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesDown = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    walkFramesDownIdle = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    collisionLayer = "collision";

    speed = 2;
    ;
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesRight[index++] = tmp[2][j];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesRightIdle[index++] = tmp[2][1];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesLeft[index++] = tmp[1][j];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesLeftIdle[index++] = tmp[1][1];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesUp[index++] = tmp[3][j];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesUpIdle[index++] = tmp[3][1];
        }
    }

    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesDown[index++] = tmp[0][j];
        }
    }
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFramesDownIdle[index++] = tmp[0][1];
        }
    }


    walkAnimationRight = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesRight);      // #11
    walkAnimationRightIdle = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesRightIdle);      // #11
    walkAnimationLeft = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesLeft);      // #11
    walkAnimationLeftIdle = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesLeftIdle);      // #11
    walkAnimationUp = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesUp);      // #11
    walkAnimationUpIdle = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesUpIdle);      // #11
    walkAnimationDown = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesDown);      // #11
    walkAnimationDownIdle = new Animation(0.2f, walkFramesDownIdle);      // #11
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();                // #12
    stateTime = 0f;                         // #13

}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(collisionLayer);
    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                        // #14
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();           // #15


    cellX = spriteX/64;
    cellY = spriteY/64;
    cellUp = layer.getCell(cellX, cellY+1);
    cellDown = layer.getCell(cellX, cellY-1);
    cellRight = layer.getCell(cellX+1, cellY);
    cellLeft = layer.getCell(cellX-1, cellY);
    blockedUp = Integer.parseInt((String) cellUp.getTile().getProperties().get("blocked"));
    if(cellY != 0)
    blockedDown = Integer.parseInt((String) cellDown.getTile().getProperties().get("blocked"));
    if(cellX != 0)
    blockedLeft = Integer.parseInt((String) cellLeft.getTile().getProperties().get("blocked"));
    blockedRight = Integer.parseInt((String) cellRight.getTile().getProperties().get("blocked"));



    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && spriteX == newX && spriteY == newY && spriteX > boundaryXLeft && blockedLeft == 0)
    {
        LastKey = 1;
        newX-=64;
        CurrentKey = 1;
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && spriteX == newX && spriteY == newY && spriteX < boundaryXRight && blockedRight == 0 )
    {
        LastKey = 0;
        newX+=64;
        CurrentKey = 0;
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX && spriteY < boundaryYUp  && blockedUp == 0)
    {
        LastKey = 2;
        newY+=64;
        CurrentKey = 2;
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX && spriteY > boundaryYDown && blockedDown == 0 )
    {
        LastKey = 3;
        newY-=64;
        CurrentKey = 3;
    }
    else if(spriteX == newX && spriteY == newY)
    {
        CurrentKey = 4;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX && spriteY > boundaryYDown && blockedDown == 2 && LastKey == 3)
    {
        LastKey = 3;
        newY-=128;
        CurrentKey = 3;
        if(collisionLayer.equals("collision"))
        {
            collisionLayer = "Inside";
            layers[1] = 4;
            layers[2] = 4;

        }
        else if(collisionLayer.equals("Inside"))
        {
            collisionLayer = "collision";
            layers[1] = 2;
            layers[2] = 3;
        }
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX && spriteY < boundaryYUp && blockedUp == 2 && LastKey == 2)
    {
        LastKey = 2;
        newY+=128;
        CurrentKey = 2;
        if(collisionLayer.equals("collision"))
        {
            collisionLayer = "Inside";
            layers[1] = 4;
            layers[2] = 4;

        }
        else if(collisionLayer.equals("Inside"))
        {
            collisionLayer = "collision";
            layers[1] = 2;
            layers[2] = 3;
        }


    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && LastKey != 1 && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX )
    {
        LastKey = 1;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && LastKey != 0 && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX )
    {
        LastKey = 0;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) && LastKey != 2 && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX )
    {
        LastKey = 2;
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN) && LastKey != 3 && spriteY == newY && spriteX == newX )
    {
        LastKey = 3;
    }


    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.ESCAPE))
    {
    Gdx.app.exit();


    }



    if(spriteX < newX)
        spriteX+=(speed);
    if(spriteX > newX)
        spriteX-=(speed);
    if(spriteY < newY)
        spriteY+=(speed);
    if(spriteY > newY)
        spriteY-=(speed);



    if(LastKey == 0 && spriteX != newX)
    {;
        currentFrame = walkAnimationRight.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);  // #16
    }
    else if(LastKey == 0 && spriteX == newX && CurrentKey == 4)
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationRightIdle.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);  // #16 
    }



    if(LastKey == 1 && spriteX != newX)
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationLeft.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true); // #16
    }
    else if (LastKey == 1 && spriteX == newX && CurrentKey == 4)   
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationLeftIdle.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true); // #16
    }

    if(LastKey == 2 && spriteY != newY)
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationUp.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);  // #16
    }
    else if (LastKey == 2 && spriteY == newY && CurrentKey == 4)   
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationUpIdle.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true); // #16
    }


    if(LastKey == 3 && spriteY != newY)
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationDown.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);  // #16
    }   
    else if (LastKey == 3 && spriteY == newY && CurrentKey == 4)   
    {
        currentFrame = walkAnimationDownIdle.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true); // #16
    }

    camera.position.set(spriteX, spriteY, 0);
    renderer.setView(camera);
    renderer.render(layers);;

    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame, spriteX, spriteY);             // #17
    spriteBatch.end();

}
@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    spriteBatch.dispose();
    renderer.dispose();
    map.dispose();



}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}








@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Comment: Give us the stack trace for the runnable jar. You'll see it by opening the console inside of the folder you exported the jar to and then executing (in the command line): "java -jar YourJar.jar"

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mygdx.game.Game_Screen.render(Game_Screen.java:181)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)

Comment: 181 is cellUp = layer.getCell(cellX, cellY+1);

Comment: Then my guess is that layer is null. You can check by printing the value for layer (you'll want to export and run in command line again).

Comment: since `cellUp` is the first layer you load, then something is happening with the object that load it, in this case, I guess there could be a problem related to `map`

Comment: So i think its actually a problem with 1.6.4 Libgdx itself, i loaded it onto my laptop(brand new) which has 1.6.5, didnt change an ounce of code, just imported into the new version, and it worked perfectly.